# Custom Load Balancer with capability to Specify Server that Should Process Request

Tags: azure, proxy, load-balancing

How to implement a custom load-balancing decision method to specify which exactly server should process a request?

Currently, I am working with Azure, so the MS solutions are more preferable (ARR or WLBS).

Each server instance may have several unique resources ("unique" means that only this particular server instance has it). 
An application creates a unique ResourceID for each resource and gives this ResourceID to a client "on demand".
The client's further requests are specified by the ResourceID.

The custom load balancer decision method should allow me to specify how:

- To get the ResourceID from the request (should work on Layer 7).
- To get the ServerInstanceID (or IP or whatever is required) based on the ResourceID (from my custom table).
- To notify the load balancer which exactly application server instance should process this request (pass the ServerInstanceID).

P.S. May be I should say "proxy" here instead of the "load balancer". But for the sake of high availability, it will require several proxy servers and the load balancer to spread traffic between them. So, a pure proxy solution will just bring another one tier to the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two useful threads on the IIS.NET Forums:

[Custom load balancing decision function](http://forums.iis.net/p/1229132/2110354.aspx)

[using URL Rewrite Module for custom load balancing](http://forums.iis.net/t/1229129.aspx)

Two main approaches are recommended:

- To use custom load balancing.
- To use custom Application Request Routing (ARR).

The most interesting thing is that different threads recommend using each other :)

Nevertheless, I will review both the suggested approaches.